# How can I get a Wikipedia article's text using Python 3 with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I have this script made in Python 3:

```
response = simple_get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics")
result = {}
result["url"] = url
if response is not None:
    html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    title = html.select("#firstHeading")[0].text
```

As you can see I can get the title from the article, but I cannot figure out how to get the text from "Mathematics (from Greek μά..." to the contents table...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

select the `<p>` tag. There are 52 elements. Not sure if you want the whole thing, but you can iterate through those tags to store it as you may. I just chose to print each of them to show the output.

```
import bs4
import requests


response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics")

if response is not None:
    html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    title = html.select("#firstHeading")[0].text
    paragraphs = html.select("p")
    for para in paragraphs:
        print (para.text)

    # just grab the text up to contents as stated in question
    intro = '\n'.join([ para.text for para in paragraphs[0:5]])
    print (intro)
```

Comment: `if response is not None` can be rewritten as `if response`. also since the content may change in the future I would have suggested to get the entire div, read only the `p` and stop when you reach the div with class "toclimit-3"

Comment: @PinoSan I think it doesn't hurt to check for None explicitly. For example `bool('' is not None)` is not the same as `bool('')`. However, in this case the None check is completely unnecessary because `response` will always be a `requests.models.Response` object. If the request fails an exception will be raised.

Comment: @t.m.adam what you are saying is true but as you said the response is not a string. So you just wanted to check that it was a valid object, not an empty string, None or an empty dictionary, ... About the exceptions, I agree we should check for exceptions in case of networks errors but also we should check for status code to be 200

Comment: @PinoSan Of course, and I too prefer the `if response` style, but you know, ["Explicit is better than implicit."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3). The problem with `if response` is that it may produce strange errors, difficult to debug. But yes, in most cases a simple boolean check should be enough.

Comment: Just because you can scrape the page, doesn't mean you should. The Wikipedia API has python packages that allow for easy and direct access to articles without undue load on the site or extra work on your end.

Answer (score 37):

There is a much, much more easy way to get information from wikipedia - **Wikipedia API**.

There is [this Python wrapper](https://github.com/martin-majlis/Wikipedia-API/), which allows you to do it in a few lines only with zero HTML-parsing:

```
import wikipediaapi

wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia('en')

page = wiki_wiki.page('Mathematics')
print(page.summary)
```

Prints:

> Mathematics (from Greek μάθημα máthēma, "knowledge, study, learning")
> includes the study of such topics as quantity, structure, space, and
> change...(omitted intentionally)

And, in general, try to avoid screen-scraping if there's a direct API available.

Answer (score 19):

Use the library `wikipedia`

```
import wikipedia
#print(wikipedia.summary("Mathematics"))
#wikipedia.search("Mathematics")
print(wikipedia.page("Mathematics").content)
```

Comment: I'd use `wikipediaapi` instead, `wikipedia` module seems to be not maintained. Though, both would do the job in a similar manner.

Answer (score 7):

You can get the desired output using `lxml` library like following.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics"

res = requests.get(url)
source = fromstring(res.content)
paragraph = '\n'.join([item.text_content() for item in source.xpath('//p[following::h2[2][span="History"]]')])
print(paragraph)
```

Using `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all("p"):
    if item.text.startswith("The history"):break
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you seem to want is the (HTML) page content without the surrounding navigation elements.  As I described in [this earlier answer from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682711/using-mediawiki-to-pull-text-from-a-wikia-page-but-it-comes-back-in-a-big-mess-i/15689191#15689191), there are (at least) two ways to get it:

- Probably the easiest way in your case is to include the parameter `action=render` in the URL, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics?action=render.  This will give you just the content HTML, and nothing else.
- Alternatively, you can also obtain the page content via the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page), as in https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Mathematics.

The advantage of using the API is that it can also give you [a lot of *other* information](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext#parse) about the page that you may find useful.  For example, if you'd like to have a list of the interlanguage links normally shown in the page's sidebar, or the categories normally shown below the content area, you can get those from the API like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&page=Mathematics&prop=langlinks|categories

(To also get the page content with the same request, use `prop=langlinks|categories|text`.)

There are several [Python libraries for using the MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python) that can automate some of nitty gritty details of using it, although the feature set they support can vary.  That said, just using the API directly from your code without a library in between is perfectly possible, too.

Answer (score 3):

To get a proper way using function, you can just get **JSON API** offered by Wikipedia :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from json import loads


def getJSON(page):
    params = urlencode({
        'format': 'json',
        'action': 'parse',
        'prop': 'text',
        'redirects' : 'true',
        'page': page})
    API = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
    response = urlopen(API + "?" + params)
    return response.read().decode('utf-8')


def getRawPage(page):
    parsed = loads(getJSON(page))
    try:
        title = parsed['parse']['title']
        content = parsed['parse']['text']['*']
        return title, content
    except KeyError:
        # The page doesn't exist
        return None, None

title, content = getRawPage("Mathematics")
```

[image]

You can then parse it with any library you want to extract what you need :)

Answer (score -1):

I use this: Via 'idx' I can determine which paragraph I want to read.

```
from from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pferde")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for idx, item in enumerate(soup.find_all("p")):
    if idx == 1:
        break
print(item.text)
```

Comment: So the first paragraph inside of the page is the content of the article? I doubt it.

Comment: No, that's just the first paragraph. You can use idx == to determine which paragraph you want to see.

Comment: I know, but besides the possibility that it may change, it's not the best option to just pull a more or less random element from the document.

Comment: @shaedrich I would like to explain it once again. The point is to iterate through the individual chapters. For example, in a Dialog like Alexa edition: Ask "what is a horse". In this case you get a lot of text. In a dialogue you can now talk say: "Read more“. Or skip this chapter.  I hope you now understand how useful this possibility of iterating is. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, not really.